# How to add an instance variable to a class to back an added method?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm new to Ruby and confused about how I can make a method in `Class` similar to `:attr_accessor`, in that it adds methods to a user class, but so these added methods have access to a pre-initialized instance variable.  It's difficult for me to explain so here is a greatly simplified sample of my efforts:

```
class Class
    def super_accessor_wow(attr_name)
        attr_name = attr_name.to_s 
        new_var_name = "@crazy_var_name"

        instance_variable_set(new_var_name, ["hi", "everyone"])

        module_eval(%Q/
            def super_#{attr_name}()
                return @#{attr_name}
            end

            def super_#{attr_name}=(value)
                @#{attr_name} = value
            end

            def greetings
                return #{new_var_name}
            end
        /)
    end
end
```

This is how I'm trying to use the new method on `Class` to modify my own class:

```
class Foo
    super_accessor_wow(:bar)
end

foo1 = Foo.new()
foo1.super_bar = 1000

puts foo1.super_bar
puts foo1.greetings.inspect
```

The first puts prints `'1000'`

The second puts prints `'nil'`, so my `instance_variable_set` call in `super_accessor_wow` seemingly has no effect.

I expected that the second puts would print `'['hi', 'everyone']'` by the way.  All of this code is contained in a single Ruby file.

Comment: I think you're looking for

instance_variable_set(new_var_name.to_sym, ["hi, "everyone"])

as instance_variable_set takes a symbol, not a string.  Unfortunately this doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `instance_variable_set` is called when you call `super_accessor_wow` during the class definition.  No instance of the class exists yet.  You create an instance of the class when you call `new`.  You could add your `@crazy_var_name` initialization to the constructor, or you could define it in the `greetings` method:

Put the default in a class variable, and initialize the instance variable in the constructor (be aware that this creates a constructor for your class, and if you then create your own constructor, it will override this one):

```
class Class
    def super_accessor_wow(attr_name)
        attr_name = attr_name.to_s
        new_var_name = "@crazy_var_name"
        new_var_name_default = "@#{new_var_name}"

        module_eval(%Q/
            #{new_var_name_default} = ["hi", "everyone"]

            def initialize()
              #{new_var_name} = #{new_var_name_default}
            end

            def super_#{attr_name}()
                return @#{attr_name}
            end

            def super_#{attr_name}=(value)
                @#{attr_name} = value
            end

            def greetings
                return #{new_var_name}
            end
        /)
    end
end

class Foo
    super_accessor_wow(:bar)
end

foo1 = Foo.new()
foo1.super_bar = 1000

puts foo1.super_bar
puts foo1.greetings.inspect
puts Foo.class_variable_get('@@crazy_var_name').inspect
puts foo1.instance_variable_get('@crazy_var_name').inspect
```

Outputs:

```
1000
["hi", "everyone"]
["hi", "everyone"]
["hi", "everyone"]
```

Define it in the `greetings` method:

```
class Class
    def super_accessor_wow(attr_name)
        attr_name = attr_name.to_s
        new_var_name = "@crazy_var_name"

        module_eval(%Q/
            def super_#{attr_name}()
                return @#{attr_name}
            end

            def super_#{attr_name}=(value)
                @#{attr_name} = value
            end

            def greetings
                #{new_var_name} = ["hi", "everyone"] unless #{new_var_name}
                return #{new_var_name}
            end
        /)
    end
end

class Foo
    super_accessor_wow(:bar)
end

foo1 = Foo.new()
foo1.super_bar = 1000

puts foo1.super_bar
puts foo1.greetings.inspect
```

Outputs

```
1000
["hi", "everyone"]
```

Comment: Creating the instance variable in greetings is the approach I eventually went with, thanks.  Can you demonstrate how to add the initialization to the constructor?  I don't understand how to do that.

Comment: Edited my answer to include initialization in the constructor.  If you create your own constructors in your classes, they'll override this constructor.  You should then instead put `@crazy_var_name = @@crazy_var_name` in your own constructors.  Or, if your instances never modify this value and only read it, then you don't even need the instance variable or the constructor, just use the class variable when you need to read it.

Comment: I see, thanks Gary.  It seems like this overall approach is quite fragile and not very open-to-extension, good to know.

Comment: Perhaps inheritance or mixins are better suited to the functionality that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comment, instance_variable_set takes a symbol, not a string, so we'll fix that up first.

```
instance_variable_set(new_var_name.to_sym, ["hi", "everyone"])
```

But the big issue is that instance_variable_set isn't being called by an instance of Foo, it's being called by the Foo class itself.  So, an instance variable is being set, but not on what you expected.

```
Foo.instance_variable_get(:@crazy_var_name).inspect
# ["hi", "everyone"]
```